# Add Custom Tab to the product admin working fine at localhost but giving wrong tab config error after uploading on server

Tags: product-attribute

I am working on product section. Here I am using module named **"Add Custom Tab"** to add Custom Tabs sections. Now the problem is it working fine at localhost but giving error on server.
**Error:-**

> Wrong tab configuration.
>   Trace: #0 [internal function]: 
> Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->addTab(’main_section’, ‘cms_page_edit_t...’) 
> #1 ...

Refering link is mentioned below

> http://www.phpcmsframework.com/2012/12/magento-steps-to-add-custom-tabs-to.html

Answer (score 1):

This happens in either of the two following cases:

1. The tab is not an instance of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`,
2. The tab is not an instance of `Varien_Object`,

I would suggest that if it works on local but not on the server then you have missed off one file or an edit to a file.

Make sure that you have copied the tab file across and that it has the following snippet:

```
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
```